# solve $\int_{c}(1-z)^2dz$; given that $c$ is the contour defined by$x=3\cos\theta$ and $y=3+3\sin\theta$; from $\theta=0$ to $\theta=\pi/2$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

As the title says I need to solve this integral, but this is the first problem I have to solve of this type and the example given by our professor is almost entirely different, and he is yet to answers my messages asking about that...

So if you can give me some insight on how can I solve this problem, I would appreciate very much.

Comment: You wrote $\oint_c$, but the curve $c$ is *not* a closed curve. What ways do you have to evaluate a line integral?

Comment: before this topic we where solving problems about derivates and Cauchy-Riemman equations, after, we did some basic defined and undefined integrals, now this, I already solved this one: $\int_{(0,1)}^{(1,4)}(2y+x^2)dx+(3x-y)dy $ for 
$y=2x^2+2$ ; but I can´t see how to make solve that one in the same way

Comment: You haven't modified the $\oint$. You didn't answer my question, either. What are the ways you know (from multivariable calculus or from your complex analysis course) to evaluate line integrals?

Comment: well, until now we just evaluate line integrals as defined integrals in an interval; for this one I think about replacing $z=(x+iy)$ then $x=3\cos\theta$ and $y=3+3\sin\theta$ and try to solve it, but I am not 100% sure about going that way

Comment: You still refuse to answer my question. What are the possible ways you know to compute a line integral, in general? What do you look for?

Comment: sorry, may be I am not understanding what you mean (english is not my first language), what I have been teached until now is to solve line integrals as defined integrals in an interval $a,b$, this is a new topic for me, the problem doesn´t say anything more, what I understand is to solve for the area under the curve because that is what we have been doing before

Comment: Do you know the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus?

Comment: yes, but not in this course

Comment: If I were you, I'd double-check that. That is the natural way to approach this problem. Or you can make a substitution in the integral once you've parametrized, but that is more work than it is worth.

Comment: the integrand is entire, so the desired integral just depends on the endpoints. this is what Ted is alluding to in his comments. please see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Generalizations

Comment: thanks for the info, I am checking it right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we can define the curve C as a set of z $\in \mathbb C$ . Note that C is not a closed curve, and so the Cauchy-Goursat theorem you mentioned in some comments is not relevant.

Let $C := \{z \in \mathbb C| z = (3cos(\theta))+(3+3sin(\theta))i , \theta \in [0,\pi/2]\}$.
Then, by definition of line integrals, we have that if C is parameterized by $(x,y)=(x(t),y(t)), z=x+yi$, the following holds: $$\int_{C} f(z)dz = \int_a^b f(z(t))\cdot z'(t)dt$$ for $t \in [a,b]$.

This is a basic property of line integrals, and I'll leave the calculations up to you.

Comment: Note $\theta \in [0,\pi/2]\}$.

Comment: @xpaul Ah yes that was an oversight. I will correct that.